# Why does my socket interface stop registering on a select() call?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I've written a program to accept TCP socket connections (server and client code below) for a Linux 2.6.14 machine.  My design is meant to ignore some (socket) inputs and respond to others.  Problem is, for the code I've written, when I ignore (don't respond), my `select(2)` function doesn't see any more data.

So in the example below, as soon as I send a `t` command, the server seems to stop hearing action on the port instance.  Up to the point I send a `t` command, the server will respond with its `Ok.`.  The server code isn't frozen as it will accept new port instances and `fork(2)`, but the port that it hasn't responded to the `t` (test) command remains seemingly frozen.  Why is this?

here is my attempt at useful captured output ...

```
~/test$ ./client-test 192.168.20.171 48884

Ok.  
Ok.
Ok.t






^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./client-test 192.168.20.171 48884
~/test$ ./client-test 192.168.20.171 48884

Ok.
Ok.
```

Here is the code for my server (error code and `#include`s removed):

```
#define PORT_NUM 48884
#define CLIENT_CMD_LENGTH  256
static void dostuff(int fd)
{
    char buf[CLIENT_CMD_LENGTH];
    char bye[] = "Bye!", ok[] = "Ok.";
    const struct timeval wait_tv = { .tv_usec = 1000000/20, .tv_sec = 0 };
    fd_set read_fd;

    do
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        int n;

        tv = wait_tv;
        FD_ZERO( & read_fd);

        FD_SET(fd, &read_fd);
        if (select(fd+1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &tv)==-1)
        {
            /* error */
        }
        else if (FD_ISSET(fd, & read_fd))
        {
            printf(".\n");
            FD_CLR(fd, & read_fd);
            n = read(fd,buf, (sizeof buf) - 1);

            switch (* buf)
            {
                case 'q': write(fd,bye,sizeof bye);
                          return;
                case 't': break; /* Ignore */
                default:  write(fd, ok, sizeof ok);
                          break;
            }
        }
    } while (1);
    return;
}

static void server_work(void)
{
     int sockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) return;
     memset((char *) &serv_addr, '\0', sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
          return;
     }
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     while (1) {
        int newsockfd, pid;
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0)
             continue;
         pid = fork();
         if (pid < 0)
             break;
         if (pid == 0)  {
             close(sockfd);
             dostuff(newsockfd);
             exit(0);
         }
         else close(newsockfd);
     } /* end of while */
     close(sockfd);
     return; /* we never get here */
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    server_work();
    return 0;
}
```

and my test client ...

```
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    do {
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s",buffer);
    } while (*buffer != 'B');
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you see happening when you walk through the code with the select()? Does your code hang, or does it continue? Does the select timeout until t is received???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your client blocks on reading right after it does its write, while the server does not send anything back on receiving a `t` and just goes back to `select(2)`. Classic deadlock.

Either skip reading on the client after sending commands that server ignores, or always send some sort of an ack from the server.

Side note - you assume that receiver gets same exact chunk of data that the sender sends. Wrong. TCP is a *byte stream* and does not preserve any sort of application-level message boundaries. You have to worry about those yourself. Two common ways of dealing with it are 1) message delimiters like zero-byte or something, and 2) pre-pending each message with its size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it will.  I'll test it by adding a select call on the client side ... as for the read lengths I get those using a `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, (void*)&nbytes)` call and a message size.  Thanks.

Comment: Adding a `select(2)` to the client test code did help.  Thanks.